# UnionBy() EF Core

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have this ef query that give me the following result

```
IQueryable<A>
| Id      | count |
| 1       | 5     |
| 2       | 6     |

IQueryable<B>
| Id      | count |
| 1       | 1     |
| 2       | 2     |
| 3       | 9     |
```

When I do

```
IQueryable<Something> C = A.union(B)
```

Result that I got is this

```
| Id      | count |
| 1       | 5     |
| 2       | 6     |
| 1       | 1     |
| 2       | 2     |
| 3       | 9     |
```

Whish is logical.

What I want is a `UnionBy(Id)`

```
IQueryable<Something> C = A.unionBy(B,c=>c.Id)
```

and this work perfectly in my case

```
| Id      | count |
| 1       | 5     |  -- FROM A
| 2       | 6     |  -- FROM A
| 3       | 9     |  -- FROM B
```

If the `Query` `A` or `B` are already executed by that I mean a `ToList()` was made it work perfectly and I have no problem in anyway.
But in my case, both queries are not executed and thus using this function result in.

> `System.InvalidOperationException` query could not be translated.

the alternative is to use a `GroupBy` however I have no idea how to replacte `UnionBy` behavior with the `GroupBy`

FYI: the query works perfectly using the `IQueryable.Union`
and it's mandatory in my case that the request stay in `IQueryable` and not executed until later

**UPDATE**

⚠️ The solution that I'm looking for must stay in `IQueryable` without a `toList()` execution

Comment: That's not a UNION result. You wouldn't use `UNION` in SQL to get these results It looks like a LEFT JOIN that falls back to the left table if there are no matches. There's no `UNION BY` in SQL anyway. EF translates LINQ to SQL and can't do anything that isn't possible in SQL

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos 

I found this as solution 
IQueryable<Something> C = A.Union(B.where(b=> A.All(a=>a.Id != b.Id))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple you filtre A From B using the following

```
IQueryable<Something> C = A.Union(B.where(b=> A.All(a=>a.Id != b.Id))
```

Answer (score -1):

"query could not be translated" usually means that EF doesn't support a certain LINQ or language construct as it can't translate it into SQL. One way to make this work is to force the evaluation of the expression client-side by adding e.g. `ToList()` or likes on the query parts before executing the `UnionBy`:

```
IQueryable<Something> C = A.ToList().UnionBy(B.ToList(),c=>c.Id);
```

Comment: I'am not allowed to use a ToList() in my case

Comment: The results show a JOIN, not UNION. There's no `UNION BY` in SQL

Comment: Or that EF doesn't have a translation written for a LINQ contruct that has a conversion to SQL.