# C# IQueryable ExceptBy unable to translate EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm facing an issue with translating the LINQ query:

```cs
Context.Elements.ExceptBy(listOfElements.Select(e => e.Id), i => i.Id).ToList();
```

However, when I execute this query, I get the following error:

> One or more errors occurred. (The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .ExceptBy(
> source2: __p_0,
> keySelector: i => i.Id)' could not be translated.

I understand that EF Core is unable to translate this LINQ expression.

My question is, is EF Core capable of translating LINQ queries that involve the `ExceptBy` method? Despite the fact that it returns an `IQueryable`, it seems to be encountering difficulties with translation.

Current version EF Core 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, is EF Core capable of translating LINQ queries that involve the ExceptBy method?

Well, the exception message is clear. Just as you [found out with `UnionBy`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74559985/861716) you need a work-around.

The query expresses that you're looking for `Elements` having `Id` values not occurring in `listOfElements.Select(e => e.Id)`. That can also be expressed using `Contains`, which is a supported LINQ operator in EF.

```cs
var ids = listOfElements.Select(e => e.Id).ToList();
var result = Context.Elements.Where(e => !ids.Contains(Id)).ToList();
```

Not only does EF execute this query alright, in EF-core 8, translation of `Contains` has been [improved for some database providers](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-ef8-preview-4/).

Comment: I completely forgot that i asked this question

Comment: thus said it's really misleading to have something that's return IQueryable and not be able to translate it what's the purpose of doing such things ?

Comment: Strictly it doesn't *return* `IQueryable`, it's just the compile-time type of the method's return object. At runtime it never comes to actually returning. Anyway, it happens all the time, there are may ways too make LINQ queries not translatable. That's the downside of the `IQueryable` interface, although, all-in-all, it's a great invention.

Answer (score 0):

I could be mistaken, but I believe as of EF Core 8, `ExceptBy` may not be supported for translation to SQL queries. Despite returning `IQueryable`, I don't think EF Core can translate `ExceptBy` into a SQL equivalent, leading to your runtime error. You'll probably need to find an alternative approach, maybe fetching data into memory first (e.g., using `ToList()`) and then applying `ExceptBy`, or using a combo of `Where` and `Contains` to achieve a similar result.